# Can I build an app that interacts with another app that I don't own?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, interaction

New here. I still didn't decide which technology I'll use to make this app, but the main feature is basically this:

  There's app A and app B (I don't own any of these);

  My app (C) needs only one role: when I login on app A it'll logout on app B and when I login on app B it'll logout on app A.

Note: Forcing app A or B to close will not logout or in.

Anyone knows a way to develop this? The app is supposed to be available on Android and iOS, I was planning to use nativescript.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks,
Diogo

Comment: If you were able to tell any random app to log in or out, that would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Are you running this on a rooted device?

Comment: You would have to collaborate with the engineers of that app to use implicit intents, broadcast receivers, or accessProviders for database interactions. You can't just violate another app's privacy. Now if you were rooted with elevated permissions you could possibly get ahold of their cached tokens and delete them, but that is a horrible idea and will only work on your device.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not because every app run in its specific sand box for security reasons. The only way to do something like that it is using broadcasts intents but the apps A and B should already be prepared to respond to a intent to log out and send a broadcast when log in. Probably it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, this won't happen as every app is running on different sandbox and there is no relation between two sandboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. Very useful. Can I use an app to close and open others? For example, If I open Spotify it automatically closes YouTube music using my app. This way would only have to do with the smartphone or tablet.